# PHP simple_html_dom and TD traversal

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to work how to traverse this specific table with the "simple_html_dom.php". I've tried many different angles and just can't get it right.  I can separate the table row by row but I can't slice up the TD values into individual components.

What I'm trying to do is take the table from this site and move the TD values into specific (array of) variables I can reliably and predictably work with. The problem is partly compounded, I think, by the fact that the TR or TDs don't have any attributes that I can 'find'.

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do');

$tds = $dom->find('table',0)->find('tr', 1)->find('td', 1);

foreach($tds as $td)
{   
    echo $td->plaintext . '</br>'
}
```

The code above finds the first TR but I would have expected `$tds` to have the value of TD cell 1. It does not though. It spits out the entire TR.

I've been over the documentation and had a good search around the net but no luck.

EDIT - Solution   (something like this):

```
    $tds = $dom->find('table',0)->find('tr');

     foreach($dom->find('tr') as $key => $tr)
     {   
        $td = $tr->find('td');

        if (isset($td[0]))
        {
            echo $td[0]->plaintext . '</br>';         // First TD column 
            //echo $td[1]->plaintext;     
            //echo $td[2]->plaintext;     
            //echo $td[3]->plaintext;    
            //echo $td[4]->plaintext;
            //echo $td[5]->plaintext;              
        }
     }
```

Comment: Can you edit into your question the HTML snippet that you want this to read? It will save people needing to visit the external website to understand the question (and that link may change or die).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`$dom->find('table',0)->find('tr', 1)->find('td', 1);`

with

`$dom->find('table',0)->find('tr', 1)->find('td');`

You're currently only fetching the first `td` when you specify the second parameter. Note that this only goes through the first table row as well.

Comment: That's great thanks. But how do I reference the TD values by number? For example TD 1 is always going to be a certain type of value and I'll want to store all of these values in an array.

Comment: You can do a `for` loop with `for($i = 0; $i < count($tds); $i++) { if($i == 0) { echo $tds[$i]; // This is always going to be the first TD } }`

Comment: OK, sorted it out. Found another snippet of code that helped me isolate the TD values. I'll update my original post.  EDIT - Ahh just noticed your post. Seems to be doing the same thing. Thanks very much for your help man!